# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Freezes (show lit up black screen) after GRUB Menu on My HP Laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, hp, freeze

Everything was working fine after installation. Today I updated software through SOFTWARE UPDATER it updated successfully and ask me to restart the laptop.
After restarting it freezes. I forcefully shutdown laptop through power button & restart again it shows GRUB MENU to select 1.UBUNTU          2. ADVANCED OPTIONS FOR UBUNTU
3. WINDOWS 
when i select ubuntu it freezes ( show lit up black screen ) 
I booted UBUNTU FROM LIVE USB & TRIED BOOT-REPAIR NOTHING HAPPENED.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pBTP8wCDCx/
Link i got from boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today and hopefully the following will also work for you.

I had updated today and was not able to boot after.
First, you can try to boot in an older kernel in advanced options.

For me, what worked was adding dis_ucode_ldr to the kernel command.

Advanced Options -> press E for the option you want to run -> add dis_ucode_ldr for the end of the line starting with linux -> press ctrl+x

It's seems like it occurred from the latest intel-microcode update so you can also have a look at topic related to that.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`

in /etc/default/grub

and execute 'update-grub'